# Nodejs obtain client's signature-algorithm offering (in relation to ERR_SSL_NO_SUITABLE_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM error)

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, openssl, lets-encrypt

I'm running a website over https (certificate provided by letsencrypt) with nodejs; lately browsers are giving a `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH` error for my site (even though nothing I'm aware of has changed server-side and cert is still valid):

[image]

I understand this issue results from having no overlap between the signature-algorithms offered by the client and server. I am wondering how to get output from nodejs related to the signature-algorithm options being offered by the client? So far I only know to set the following environment var:

```
export NODE_DEBUG='tls,https'
```

which gets me insufficient output from my server, looking like this:

```
TLS 3190484: net.Server.on(connection): new TLSSocket
TLS 3190484: server _init handle? true
TLS 3190484: server initRead handle? true buffered? 0
TLS 3190484: server onhandshakestart
TLS 3190484: server onerror [Error: 00C8D22F147F0000:error:0A000076:SSL routines:tls_choose_sigalg:no suitable signature algorithm:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/t1_lib.c:3252:
] {
  library: 'SSL routines',
  reason: 'no suitable signature algorithm',
  code: 'ERR_SSL_NO_SUITABLE_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM'
} had? false
```

**How can I obtain the list of the signature-algorithms offered by the client?**

Comment: Have you checked your site with [ssllabs](https://ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html)? Apart from that you might do a packet capture with wireshark and then look at what the client offers inside the ClientHello.

Comment: I hadn't realized there were excellent free online ssl debuggers! I solved my https problem with ssllabs - thanks a lot! I may keep this question open though; I think it would be interesting to get an answer.

Comment: Given that you solved your problem it would be interesting what it was and how you solved it.